# How to flush old content before rendering new content in React?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a basic blog app where the index page lists all the blog posts for the user. When the user clicks on a blog post, he is redirected to the blog post page which has the title and content. If the user goes back to the index page and then clicks on another blog post, for a brief second the contents of the first blog post is shown and then the new blog post is displayed. How do I solve this?

Note: When the user visits a blog post page, an ajax call is made to fetch the contents of that post.

Comment: If you are using a state variable in list page, empty the state variable which contains the data to be rendered in the redirected page just when the user clicks the blog post

Answer (score 0):

You can empty the state of your Blog Post `Component` in one of the component [life cycle methods](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-lifecycle-methods-to-a-class) : `componentWillUnmount()`

Let me go more briefly:

1. You should have one more **`actionType`** say `RESET_BLOG_POST`
2. Action for resetting `state` of your BlogPost Component which empties all component data in your `actions`.
3. And I think you know how to handle this action in your reducer
4. And in your component call this action in `componentWillUnmount()`

something like this

```
componentWillUnmount(){
  this.props.resetBlogPost(); //this dehydrates your component.
}
```

So it clears the current state of your component.

Comment: Unmount is spelled with m instead of n. Be careful with copy-pasting :)